# Show dial up connection status in Task Manager

Tags: windows-8, performance, internet, task-manager, dial-up

In Windows 8.1, Task Manager shows Wi-Fi, Disk, CPU usage graph in Performance tab. But, it doesn't shows usage of a dial up internet connection. How can I add dial up stats in task manager.

Here are screenshots of my task manager and network connections.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use dial-up connection with "Mobile partner" app, and setting connection type as NDIS:

[image: Mpartner]

after it's connected, i open task manager..

[image: Task manager]

Thanks.